# React hook form dismiss errors when input cleared

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a large form, mode is set to all, validate with yup, when i clear my inputs the error stays, is there some setting in react hook form that can reset errors when i clear inputs?

Comment: if you have any field that you're setting with the ```setValue``` hook from ```react-hook-form``` then you'll need to clear it manually with another hook provided by ```react-hook-form```